# extracting data from text file using C#

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamreader

i am trying to extract data from a text file using c#
the contents of the file are like this-

```
2002/01/10 00:44:51.53  40.4415 -126.0167  25.37  3.92   Md   56 269  147 0.29 NCSN   21208454
```

now i want the data from the text file to be stored in variables like this-

date=2002/01/10

time=00:44:51.53

lat=40.4415  and so on..

here is the snippet of code that i have used

```
     public class data
  {
  public string date, time;
  public double lat, lon,depth,mag;
  }

 class Program
 {

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dt;
    List<data> gd = new List<data>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("E:\\op.html"))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() > 0)
        {
            string str;
            string[] arr;
            str = sr.ReadLine();
            arr = str.Split(' ');
            data d = new data();
            d.date = arr[0];
            //d.time = arr[1];
            //d.lat = Convert.ToDouble( arr[2]);
            //d.lon = Convert.ToDouble(arr[3]);
            //d.depth = Convert.ToDouble(arr[4]);
            //d.mag = Convert.ToDouble(arr[5]);


            Console.WriteLine(d.date);
            //Console.WriteLine(d.time);
            //Console.WriteLine(d.lat);
            //Console.WriteLine(d.lon);
            //Console.WriteLine(d.depth);
            //Console.WriteLine(d.mag);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

but i only get the value of d.date,can't get the rest of the values. the lines marked with "//" throws an error "IndexOutOfBound" Error.. how to fix this?

Comment: Check the value of str after the call to ReadLine. Is it what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class data
{
    public string date, time,mag;
    public double lat, lon, depth;
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;

        string dt;
        List<data> gd = new List<data>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("E:\\op.html"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string [] arr = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                while (sr.Peek() > 0)
                {

                    string[] s = new string[] { " " };
                    char[] c = new char[] { ' ' };
                    str = sr.ReadLine();
                    arr = str.Split(c);

                    data d = new data();
                    d.date = arr[0];
                    d.time = arr[1];

                    d.lon =Convert.ToDouble(arr[3]);
                    d.depth = Convert.ToDouble (arr[4]);
                    d.mag = arr[8];
                    //                    File.WriteAllText("E:\\abc.txt",d.date);

                    Console.WriteLine(d.date);
                    Console.WriteLine(d.time);
                    //Console.WriteLine(d.lat);
                    Console.WriteLine(d.lon);
                    Console.WriteLine(d.depth);
                    Console.WriteLine(d.mag);
                    int x = arr[0].Length;
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `httpWReq.Proxy.Credentials` to a `NetworkCredentials` with your proxy's authentication info.

Comment: Isn't that a local file, though?